# Trying to setup magento2 , missing Extension intl. -XAMPP

Tags: magento2, php, extensions, php-7, xampp

I'm trying to setup **magento2** but this error `1 missing PHP Extension intl`.  already made me crazy... tried so many solution like edit php.ini :

**From:**

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

**To**

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Also copying all 6 files:

```
icudt57.dll,icuin57.dll,icuio57.dll,icule57.dll,iculx57.dll,icuuc57.dll
```

From php folder to apache\bin

Tried all those and it didnt fixed it , can you please help me?

**When I command php -m in cmd , module intl is missing.**

Also in another check commant it gives back this:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score -1):

=> Please try Below Commands :

- Installed: sudo apt-get install php5-intl
- Restarted the Apache: sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: He uses windows...

Comment: Yes OS windows 10. Not linux @Pranay K